# GIT patch bug - Failing for basic patch

Tags: git, msysgit, mingw32

I'm creating some patches from a cloned GitHub repo to which I've added a series of small commits, since I want forked repos to be able to back-patch.
I'm using the latest MinGW based Windows version of GIT from `msysgit.github.io` (ver 1.9.5).

The first patch is just changing the script tags in a series of HTML files to point to a later version of jQuery, so it's just simple line replacement.

I get the commit guids with `git log -3` and then create the patch with eg.

```
git diff e004912b5ce29ac0d0cb04df50fe66db5e3af9ea 574391effbdfcb187cf5695e28558d5ace5bdefd > ../patches/test.patch
```

The strange thing is, when I apply the patch with

```
 git apply ../patches/test.patch
```

to the original repo at commit e004912b5ce29ac0d0cb04df50fe66db5e3af9ea it fails with 'patch failed' and 'patch does not apply messages.

It's erroring out on one file, but if I remove that section of the diff, the patch works. I'm using Notepad++ so I can see tabs/spaces and line endings as CR/CRLF and it's not that.

Even weirder, when I apply the edited patch, then manually apply the failing changes to that one file, commit and create a new patch, it not only is byte-identical to the first patch, it also fails identically.

So I'm 100% sure this is a bug. There is NO problem with the files or the patch. It's preventing me from releasing these patches.

What could be causing this? I'm copying a local version of the cloned repo which is at e004912b5ce29ac0d0cb04df50fe66db5e3af9ea, so I don't see how index could be corrupted or anything like that. Is this a known issue with Windows GIT?

Edit:

OK it WAS the line endings.  Take a look at this (shown in Notepad++), AutoToolTips.html being the problem child:

[image]

So find/replacing `\r\n` with `\n` here fixed the issue.
Apologies, I was sure I had checked this earlier.

There still remains the mystery of why this particular file was treated differently to every other file in the patch.
In the GitHub repo, all files are set to LF (unix line termination). Git for windows is set up to translate all files to CRLF format and then back to LF again when committing. This is consistent - all my local files have CRLF termination.

Is this possibly something that is hidden in a Git meta property for that file specifically? If so, how would I find the property ?

Comment: extra kudos for decoding the guid and working out the repo ;-)

Comment: well a Google search gets [this](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) ... can you paste the failing hunk of your patch?

Comment: Tell me about your line endings. </therapist_mode>

Comment: Initial problem worked around. However I'm still treating it as a bug. I don't know why or how the bad patch formatting was introduced just for that one file. I don't have a .gitattibutes file.